A change of variables for a complex function
Consider the function $\phi(z):=\tanh((\pi/4) z)$, which maps $\mathbb{R} +i$ bijectively to $\{e^{i\theta} ; \theta \in (0,\pi)\}$, i.e. the upper half of the Torus. I am working through a paper where the author claims that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \frac{\phi(z)+e^{i\theta}}{\phi(z)-e^{i\theta}}d \theta= \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\phi(z) + \phi(x+i)}{\phi(z)-\phi(x+i)} \cdot \frac{\phi'(x+i)}{\phi(x+i)}dx
\end{align*}
for a fixed $z\in \mathbb{C}$. I don't understand where the factor $1/\phi(x+i)$ comes from, isn't this just an application of a standard change of variables formula? Apparently I am missing something. Can someone help me with that or direct me to a formula I can use?

When you substitute $e^{i\theta} = \phi(x+i)$, you get a Jacobian factor in the integral given by
$$
ie^{i\theta} d\theta = \phi'(x+i) dx \implies d\theta = -i\frac{\phi’(x+i)}{\phi(x+i)} dx.
$$
